# Did God use man as a vehicle to bring about death?

Tags: nature-of-god, apologetics, eternal-life

Before creation there would have been no death. All of the Angels God created are eternal.

When God Created everything then time was also created, but Earth and time are both temporary creations.

All scripture is quoted from the King James translation.

> Revelation 21:1  ***And I saw a new heaven and a new earth: for the first heaven and the first earth are passed away***; and the sea is no more.

Revelation 10:5 and 6

> And the angel which I saw stand upon the sea and upon the earth lifted up his hand to heaven,  And sware by him that liveth for ever and ever, who created heaven, and the things that therein are, and the earth, and the things that therein are, and the sea, and the things which are therein, ***that there should be time no longer***:

Death will be burned forever in the lake of fire:

> Revelation 20:14  And death and hell were cast into the lake of fire. This is the second death.

The Earth is apparently a waiting place for Satan and his demons.

> Revelation 12:9  And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, called the Devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world: he was cast out into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him.

and then after the great white throne judgment they along with the unsaved will be cast into the lake of fire to be tormented forever.

Revelation 20:10 through 15

> And the devil that deceived them was cast into the lake of fire and brimstone, where the beast and the false prophet are, and shall be tormented day and night for ever and ever. And I saw a great white throne, and him that sat on it, from whose face the earth and the heaven fled away; and there was found no place for them.  And I saw the dead, small and great, stand before God; and the books were opened: and another book was opened, which is the book of life: and the dead were judged out of those things which were written in the books, according to their works. And the sea gave up the dead which were in it; and death and hell delivered up the dead which were in them: and they were judged every man according to their works. And death and hell were cast into the lake of fire. This is the second death. And whosoever was not found written in the book of life was cast into the lake of fire.

Since being cast into the lake of fire is the second death and physical death is the first death, could it be that God used man to create death that Satan and the rebellious angels could experience the second death?

Comment: As worded, I think this is off-topic as a general philosophical question. A very interesting idea, but all answers are going to be primarily opinion based. I'm not sure how you might edit this to put it on-topic and still get answers you are looking for.

Comment: On the question content, the way you have portrayed things and the sequence of events is not even close to agreed on by Christians. A little nit-pick: Angels are immortal, meaning they don't die. Only God is eternal, having no beginning *or* end. That's pretty well agreed upon and it likely what you meant.

Comment: @fredsbend: Re: immortal vs. eternal, humans are promised eternal life--that doesn't mean we're granted life that had no beginning.

Comment: @Flimzy Right. It gets sticky. I still have trouble defining those terms, as they are regularly used differently in the Bible and in practice. It's just the way the OP was written implies that Angels and God are on the same level: not created but always were. -- Idk, what I'm talking about. It says created. Ignore me.

Comment: not so philosophical, there is some evidence, satan was the accuser at the time, he found a way to accuse them. Not so much God but satan was behind this. Satan wanted a scapegoat for his crimes.